# How to programmatically specify NiFi properties before starting up NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi, properties-file

We are starting NiFi up on multiple containers and we are using a script to do this for us. Each device has a separate IP address which needs to be part of the nifi.remote.input.host. Is there no other way of specifying this property other than entering it in the nifi.properties file?

There is a script that I will be running which will spawn multiple containers. These containers run a startup script which then starts NiFi. If there is a way to change the property as I have asked above, then all the startup script would need to do is retrive the IP address from ifconfig and pass the value. Otherwise, the script would have to handle the nifi.properties file, which, I think, would be a less elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

That property can only be specified through nifi.properties. You can probably have a nifi.properties file with a placeholder like nifi.remote.input.host=REMOTE_INPUT_HOST and then just do a replace on the file with the real host/ip.

Comment: That is a nice idea. Thanks Bryan.